# How do I queue perl subroutines to a thread queue instead of data?

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

**Background**: 
In reading how to multithread my perl script, I read (*from http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#BUGS-AND-LIMITATIONS*)

> On most systems, frequent and continual creation and destruction of
>   threads can lead to ever-increasing growth in the memory footprint of
>   the Perl interpreter. While it is simple to just launch threads and
>   then ->join() or ->detach() them, for long-lived applications, it is
>   better to maintain a pool of threads, and to reuse them for the work
>   needed, using queues to notify threads of pending work.

My script will be long-lived; it's an PKI LDAP directory monitoring daemon that will always be running. The enterprise monitoring solution will generate an alarm if it stops running for any reason. My script will check that I can reach another PKI LDAP directory, as well as validate revocation lists on both.

**Problem**: Everything I can find on google shows passing variables (e.g. scalars) to the thread queue rather than the subroutine itself... I think I'm just not understanding how to implement a thread queue properly compared to how you implement a thread (without queues).


**Question 1**: How can I "maintain a pool of threads" to avoid the perl interpreter from slowly eating up more and more memory?
**Question 2**: (Unrelated but while I have this code posted) Is there a safe amount of sleep at the end of the main program so that I don't start a thread more than once in a minute? 60 seems obvious but could that ever cause it to run more than once if the loop is fast, or perhaps miss a minute because of processing time or something?

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature ":5.10";
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use Proc::Daemon;
#

### Global Variables
use constant false => 0;
use constant true  => 1;
my $app = $0;
my $continue = true;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = false };

# Directory Server Agent (DSA) info
my @ListOfDSAs = (
    { name => "Myself (inbound)",
      host => "ldap.myco.ca",
      base => "ou=mydir,o=myco,c=ca",
    },
    { name => "Company 2",
      host => "ldap.comp2.ca",
      base => "ou=their-dir,o=comp2,c=ca",
    }
);    
#

### Subroutines

sub checkConnections
{   # runs every 5 minutes
    my (@DSAs, $logfile) = @_;
    # Code to ldapsearch
    threads->detach();
}

sub validateRevocationLists
{   # runs every hour on minute xx:55
    my (@DSAs, $logfile) = @_;
    # Code to validate CRLs haven't expired, etc
    threads->detach();
}

#

### Main program
Proc::Daemon::Init;

while ($continue)
{
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);

    # Question 1: Queues??

    if ($min % 5 == 0 || $min == 0)
        { threads->create(&checkConnections, @ListOfDSAs, "/var/connect.log"); }

    if ($min % 55 == 0)
        { threads->create(&validateRevocationLists, @ListOfDSAs, "/var/RLs.log"); }

    sleep 60; # Question 2: Safer/better way to prevent multiple threads being started for same check in one matching minute?
}

# TERM RECEIVED
exit 0;
__END__
```

Comment: Silly question: why use threads?  Why not check the DSAs one at a time?

Comment: Valid question! a) The server has plenty of cores, so I figured "why not use them?" and b) I'm a total geek and wanted to learn proper threading techniques for future scripts too (and I hate taking the easy way out hehe). The subroutines send SNMP traps to a centralized monitoring server if problems are found so my main script doesn't really care about return values, so this felt like the way to go.

Comment: I can relate to those reasons, but I think in this case you should really not add the complexity of threads, unless there is a compelling reason to use them.

Comment: `$min % 55 == 0` means `$min == 55` (given the range of $min)

Comment: `$min % 5 == 0 || $min == 0` is the same as just `$min % 5 == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

my $check_conn_q      = Thread::Queue->new();
my $validate_revoke_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @threads;
push @threads, async {
   while (my $job = $check_conn_q->dequeue()) {
      check_conn(@$job);
   }
};
push @threads, async {
   while (my $job = $validate_revoke_q->dequeue()) {
      validate_revoke(@$job);
   }
};

while ($continue) {
   my ($S,$M,$H,$m,$d,$Y) = localtime; $m+=1; $Y+=1900;

   $check_conn_q->enqueue([ @ListOfDSAs, "/var/connect.log" ])
      if $M % 5 == 0;

   $validate_revoke_q->enqueue([ @ListOfDSAs, "/var/RLs.log" ])
      if $M == 55;

   sleep 30;
}

$check_conn_q->end();
$validate_revoke_q->end();
$_->join for @threads;
```

---

I'm not sure parallelisation is needed here. If it's not, you could simply use

```
use List::Util qw( min );

sub sleep_until {
   my ($until) = @_;
   my $time = time;
   return if $time >= $until;
   sleep($until - $time);
}

my $next_check_conn = my $next_validate_revoke = time;
while ($continue) {
   sleep_until min $next_check_conn, $next_validate_revoke;
   last if !$continue;

   my $time = time;
   if ($time >= $next_check_conn) {
      check_conn(@ListOfDSAs, "/var/connect.log");
      $next_check_conn = time + 5*60;
   }

   if ($time >= $next_validate_revoke) {
      validate_revoke(@ListOfDSAs, "/var/RLs.log");
      $next_validate_revoke = time + 60*60;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm starting to understand many of the examples... You're sending the arguments/parameters to the queue! Quick question related to your first block of code: where you have push @threads, async {} I guess check_conn & validate_revoke are calling my subs? (called checkConnections & validateRevocationLists in my code?)

Comment: `async` returns the thread (like `thread->create`) does. This allows us to `join` them later. Using joinable threads instead of using detached threads makes it so you don't exit while a thread is in the middle of doing something. (`->end` will make sure the thread doesn't start a new job, though.)

Comment: `check_conn` is `checkConnections`. I renamed your subs (to be more conventionally named and to save typing). Me bad.

Comment: all good! just making sure I (or future ppl searching) understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just running the checks one at a time, as there does not appear to be a compelling reason to use threads here, and you don't want to add unnecessary complexity to a program that will be running all the time.

If you do want to learn how use a thread pool, there are [examples included with the `threads` module](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/threads-1.86/examples/).  There is also a [`Thread::Pool` module](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Thread-Pool-0.33/lib/Thread/Pool.pm) that may be useful.

As for ensuring you don't repeat the checks in the same minute, you are correct that `sleeping` for 60 seconds will be inadequate.  No matter what value you choose to sleep, you will have edge cases in which it fails: either it will be slightly shorter than a minute, and you will occasionally have two checks in the same minute, or it will be slightly longer than a minute, and you will occasionally miss a check altogether.

Instead, use a variable to remember when the task was last done. You can then use a shorter sleep time without worrying about multiple checks per minute.

```
my $last_task_time = -1;
while ($continue)
{
    my $min = (localtime(time))[1];

    if ($last_task_time != $min && 
          ($min % 5 == 0 || $min > ($last_task_time+5)%60))
    { 
        #Check connections here.

        if ($min == 55 || ($last_task_time < 55 && $min > 55))
        { 
           #Validate revocation lists here.
        }

        $last_task_time = $min;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep 55; #Ensures there is at least one check per minute.
    }
}
```

**Update:** I fixed the code so that it will recover if the last task ran too long. This would be fine if it occasionally takes a long time.  If the tasks are frequently taking longer than five minutes, though, you need a different solution (threads would probably make sense in that case).